# MySQL - Maintaining multiple schema instances

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out the best way to store and maintain multiple instances of the same schema for use with CodeIgniter.

I initially thought simply having multiple databases all with the same tables would be the simplest method. Another option though is to just use one database and duplicate the schema tables with varying prefixes.

Having multiple databases just seems like a much more logical structure and would be easy to navigate (at least in terms of phpMyAdmin), but may run into issues with user permissions and backup routines may be more troublesome.

On the other hand, a single database with potentially hundreds of tables (each instance would have roughly 15-20 tables) might be easier to maintain and run queries on as there would be no need to store the database name, but it would obviously be a lot messier.

The most important thing is that it is secure and easily modifiable (for example if I need to add a field to all instances of a particular table).

Any thoughts on what the best practice is, or if there are better options?

Comment: I don't know what multiple instances of the same schema means.

Comment: Say I have a schema with four tables, that is one instance. If I create a new instance, I'm creating those same four tables, but either in another database or in the same database with different names.

Comment: i would use multiple databases. you will have to write your own script for updating chnages in multiple tables. i have done something similar